# Trying to run test using 'rspec' but can't due to my omniauth.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, omniauth

Has my whole testing ability been render useless with the inclusion of Omniauth?
When running any 'rspec' commands I immediately recieve this error:

```
config/initializers/omniauth.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant TWITTER_KEY (NameError)
```

TWITTER_KEY has been defined in my /config/environment/development.rb.  Why doesn't Rspec know this? how can I inform rspec of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution: define TWITTER_KEY  in /config/environment/test.rb